# NULL pointer returned by new and malloc, why?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void multiplier_matrice_vecteur (char * v0, char * A, int N)
{
    int i,j,k;
    char somme;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) //On fait N calculs car c'est une matrice 1xN
    {
        //On fait N additions + multiplications
        somme = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            somme += v0[i] * A[i * N + j];
        }
        v0[i] = somme;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    bool premiereLignefaite = false;
    //Lire le fichier
    FILE * graphe = fopen("graphe.txt", "r");
    //Fichier de sortie
    FILE * resultat = fopen("resultat.txt", "w");
    int nbr1, nbr2;
    int N;
    char *matrice; //pointeur vers la matrice d'adjacence

    //Ligne lue
    static char ligne[50];

    while (fgets(ligne, 50, graphe) != NULL) //retourne 0 quand on a end-of-file
    {
        //La premiere ligne est différente
        if (premiereLignefaite == false) {
            //Initialiser une matrice d'adjacence NxN
            sscanf(ligne, "%d %d", &nbr1, &nbr2);
            N = nbr1;
            matrice =  new char(nbr1 * nbr1); //Memoire dynamique pour la matrice dadjacence n x n
            memset(matrice, 0, nbr1*nbr1);
            premiereLignefaite = true;
            continue;
        }
        //On construit notre matrice d'adjacence
        sscanf(ligne, "%d %d", &nbr1, &nbr2);
        matrice[nbr1 * N + nbr2    ] = 1;
    }

    printf("Matrice d'adjacence %dx%d : \n", N, N);
    //Affichage de la matrice d'adjacence
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            printf("%c ", matrice[i * N + j] + '0');
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //Application de l'algo étapes par étapes
    double tolerance = 0.00001; //Niveau de tolérance de la méthode
    char * v0; //vecteur propre taille N
    char * v; //vecteur tampon
    int valeur; //valeur propre
    int valeur_tamp; //valeur propre tampon

    //Initialiser v0
    v0 = new char(N);
    memset(v0, 1, N);

    //Initialiser A (déja fait)
    //Initialiser tolérance (deja fait)

    valeur = 0;
    while (1)
    {

        valeur_tamp = valeur;
        //Multiplication du vecteur par la matrice
        multiplier_matrice_vecteur(v0, matrice, N);
    }

    //Désallocation de la mémoire
    delete matrice;

    //Fermeture des fichiers etc
    fclose(graphe);
    fclose(resultat);

    return 0;
}
```

So this is the program I have been coding since 2PM on my laptop. I am using Visual Studio 2008 and Windows 7 64 bits. I'm coding, everything's going fine. When I try to test my program, the line :

```
v0 = new char(N);
```

Gives me an exception. I try getting my memory with malloc and calloc and what do I get? A null pointer!! I have 4 gigs of ram on my machine and there's no way I can't get 9 bytes of memory here. I don't understand this at all.

For those who have Visual Studio 2008 and want to test under the same environnement, you will need the file graphe.txt, here's that file :

```
9 20
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 2
1 3
1 5
2 0
2 1
2 3
3 1
3 2
3 4
4 3
5 1
5 6
5 7
6 5
6 8
7 5
8 6
```

I thought that this was a machine problem, So I come back home, I try the program on my desktop computer and it's the same problem...

I'd have to try on GCC but since I'm always using Visual C++ I want to solve the problem on this environment...

EDIT: The following code now works. For some reason, if you use parentheses in the first new, it will work, but the next time you use new, it won't work!!
If I put both new allocations with [] syntax, it works. If I put the first new allocation with [] and the second one with (), it also works. WEIRD. Anyways, i'll be using [] from now on... Thank you all.

Comment: What's the value if `N` when control reaches that line with the exception?

Comment: Are you sure the exception is not here?  `memset(v0, 1, N);`

Comment: No, it happens before trying to do the memset here.

Comment: Parentheses allocate a single char and initialize the value to N. Square brackets allocate an array of characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
matrice = new char[nbr1 * nbr1];
```

and remember to free with

```
delete[] matrice;
```

Comment: We have `boost::array` or `std::vector` for dynamic arrays in C++, BTW.

Comment: You are suggesting I use [] instead of ().Ok but It does the same thing.

Comment: @toto: Erm, no? `new char[n]` allocates `n` uninitialized characters, whereas `new char(n)` allocates a single character initialized to the value `n`.

Comment: @Kos: everyone suggests that, but I've avoided STL for little things since writing dll plugins under windows, where including the standard library increased the dll size massively. I guess things might have improved since...or there are cases where the STL isn't appropriate.

Comment: @sje397: If you're reinventing the wheel every time you write a function, why would anyone want to use your dll instead of using the stl? That's what it's there for. You'll never be able to manage your own memory correctly.

Comment: @sje397: I agree STL isn't the panacea... but the code in the question is clearly from a C++ newbie. Knowing pros and cons of STL and making a choice is one thing... ignoring the existence of STL is another.

Comment: @Falmarri: because my dlls did things the STL doesn't - they didn't replace the STL. I've managed my own memory correctly many times. The STL is good - worth knowing, useful, etc - but it's not always necessary. @6502: it's good for 'newbies' to understand 'new' and 'delete' as well. I would argue that it's best to work your way up, not down.

Comment: @sje397: I think that the best way of learning C++ is indeed starting to really understand the roots (i.e. pointers, memory) and coming only later to abstractions like vector. But I still think that one should approach C++ with a bit of reading first because the language is too complex, asymmetrical and dangerous to be learned by experimenting. I think the ideal path is starting with a good grasp of C first and then reading a good C++ text. And IMO someone that took the time for the reading wouldn't use naked pointers and memset here.

Comment: @6502: I do agree with you. I'd rather give the OP the benefit of the double though and assume there may be some reason for doing it the way he does. Hopefully these comments are of useful if that's not the case.

Answer (score 4):

Your code has a bad bug:

```
//Initialiser v0
v0 = new char(N);
memset(v0, 1, N);
```

You probably mean "new char[N]" to allocate N characters. But your code only allocates 1 byte with value N. Then you overwrite memory from V0 to VO+n-1 to 1. Who knows what memory you are overwriting here.

Comment: +1 nice shot, I couldnt see this, I am losing my C... maybe we should advise him to use std::vector instead of C arrays...

Answer (score 3):

the immediate problem is your use of round parentheses instead of square brackets.

but use std::vector instead of raw arrays. it does the allocation and deallocation for you. correctly.

cheers & hth.,

Comment: No, parentheses are valid when allocating a single character. That's the syntax for passing a value to the constructor.

Comment: @Jonathan: wtf. do you mean by "no"? and the rest of your comment, yes literally true, but did you at all check what the code is *about*?

Comment: I admit I spent limited time studying the code. But my point was simply that use of parentheses this way is valid. If your point was that he should've allocated an array rather than a single character, then I agree with you. I guess I just don't see that as a problem with parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

I can't test your code, but you do something **not clean**.

You don't initialize you variable `int N;`
you should at least write `int N =0;`

if ever your loop makes that N is not initialized the way you want, then your N is a random integer, mayber far greater than the memory available when you use it with `new`.

Just my little supposition.

EDIT: i cannot test your code cause I don't have an eample of you "graphe.txt"... so i read nothing from file

Comment: This is what I was thinking too; +1. Also I'd like to add that stuff like this can be avoided more easily if you turn warnings up all the way.

Comment: @Cam it seems we have all erred between the nightmares of uninitialized integers ;-)

Comment: @toto ok this not the problem, but you should not write code this way. **Always initialize your variables when you can.**

Comment: This is why it's bad to code after 2:00 PM. It's an after-lunch time. Better go to sleep for an hour or tow :)

Comment: I'M YOUNG AND I'M IN COLLEGE. I chose STUDIES + SLEEP BUT NO GIRLS SO I HAVE PLENTY OF SLEEP THANK YOU, EVEN THO I CRY AT NIGHT.

Comment: @Stephane: Indeed. Plus it's parentheses and not square brackets anyway, so that shouldn't raise an exception. I find it hard to believe that line raises an exception.

Answer (score 0):

v0 = new char(N) allocates a single character with the value N. Did you mean to allocate an array?

Beyond that, your question is a little confusing. Does it return null or raise an exception. The same line won't do both.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made several mistakes

1. For sure at least a small coding one because as sje397 pointed out you were allocating a single char and not an array. I hope you know the difference and that it was only a typo.
2. A rather more serious one of using C++ without first reading anything about it (no one knowing C++ would use `new` that way... that's a job for std::vector). C++ is not a language you can hope to learn to any decent extent by mere experimentation. It's sad but it's a fact... in C++ when you make mistakes you get the dreaded Undefined Behavior monster and that's not an easy way to learn; this is also especially true for C++ because the language is both complex and illogical in many areas and it's this way because of historical accidents (heritage, youth errors, committee effect) ... no matter how smart you are there is no way you can guess history: history must be studied. If you are interested in learning C++ then please do yourself a favor and pick any good C++ book and start first by reading a bit... C++ is a very nice and powerful weapon to own, but it can easily become your worst nightmare if you try attacking it from the wrong side.
3. A VERY serious one with the attitude. When a program has a problem then 99.999% of the times the problem is in YOUR code. It's not a bug in the compiler. It's not a bug in OS. It's not defective RAM. It's just your code that is wrong so you must search and fix the problem. Keeping the habit of thinking FIRST that the problem is in someone else's code won't really take you far in programming.

Comment: Hey, you are right but I think you're a bit rude here. If I like to work with pure arrays instead of vector then that's my choice. vector is in the library, char is in the language, so i am doing C++ alright. I agree with point number 3.

Comment: I'm sorry if it sounded rude but it's an advice coming from my personal experience. I wrote a lot of C++ programs before taking the time to actually study the language and believe me it makes a HUGE difference. If you want to use raw memory this way even knowing std::vector then that's for sure a choice like if you want to go with malloc(1+strlen(...))/strcpy instead of std::string but there are very few cases in which this wouldn't be a mistake. Your code in so many points really screams you never took the time to read any C++ text. Believe me it can really make a difference; give it a try.